# Does an element in BEM need to be inside a block?

Tags: css, bem

I have a question regarding BEM. Is it ok to have a `.block__element` on its own with having a `block` as a parent? I'm building a site with WordPress where there are a lot of other classes from the theme, page builder and plugins, so the need to have parent `block`s sometimes makes it all a bit messy. So is this then ok, to have a `block__element` on its own and then style it via SCSS, or should I add a `block` to the footer to do this properly?

HTML

```
<footer id="footer">
 <div class="theme-class page-builder-class">
  <div class="footer-block__text">Some footer element text</div>
 </div>
</footer>
```

CSS

```
#footer .footer-block__text {
 color: #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: You should add a block to the footer to do this properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I* think you can mix BEM classes with others in a lot of cases. BEM could be mixed with other methodologies, with some old code, or even with medium specific classes.

For example, I used to mix methodologies:

- **You have specific changes to make to a block that are not based on logic**. In this case, I would prefer use a utility class (ex: `.u-uppercase`) that will be shorter to write and available for every blocks, than to write an non-logical BEM modifier (ex: `.title--uppercase`)
- **You have a layout class (that distribute the screen space) that your repeat in multiple blocks**. In this case, I would prefer use an OOCSS object class (ex: `.o-container`) that will reduce BEM complexity, than to write the same BEM element everywhere (ex: `.header__container`).

You could find a great presentation about extending BEM here: [Modular CSS at Rangle](http://rangle.github.io/intro-to-modular-css/).

From my experience, I tried to mix OOCSS (with `l-` prefix) and BEM classes (with `p-`  prefix) when building this website https://www.netalis.fr. It was strange at first, but finally very useful and stable.

An example from netalis website:

```html
<!-- HEADER BLOCK -->
<div class="p-header p-header--hero">

    <!-- NESTED BLOCK -->
    <div class="p-menu"></div>

    <!-- OBJECT CLASS -->
    <div class="l-container">

        <!-- HEADER ELEMENT -->
        <div class="p-header__content"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It works because theses external classes are:

1. **Isolated** from BEM classes, for example no selector that mix both (`.p-header > .l-container`)
2. **Immutable**, the utilities/object classes should not change over time.

So my question is: *Does your `page-builder-class` isolated and immutable?*

Comment: I have got to the same conclusion for all my projects. I have created a combination of BEM, ABEM, utility classes and some of my own goodies. so now I have this: `s-header__text (s-u)-textUpper;` (the s-u is optional), the `s` is the prefix for my classes so I quickly can see all of them in the inspector, because I'm using a WordPress site with a paid theme and page builder it adds a lot of other classes in the mix. and I can now either use a `u-` class for just things that don't have a block in front of them and I don't just want to create a random block to do some text-centre stuff. Thanks!

Comment: So with all of this I really just push it all togheter. the camelCase really helps with readability. Now the issue I have with utilitie classes is that I shouldn't use them all to often, wich is a habbit of mine now... I just think that I need to create some Wordpress and normal sites with my BEM version

Answer (score 3):

My opinion would be **no**, for two reasons:

- BEM is designed to enforce module separation, so that they are easier to reason about, and to minimize the risk of styles leaking from one module or block to another. If you're mixing BEM blocks with non-BEM code, you're not really doing BEM.
- Blocks are designed carefully and assume inheritance from `block` to `block__element`. Without seeing any code I of course can't say for sure, but it's possible that the styling of `block__element` depends on inheriting some rules from `block`. If the library designer can't assume that all `block__element`s have a `block` ancestor, then there's no benefit in structuring the library this way. For instance, if `block` defines `display:flex`, and `block__element` has `flex-grow:1`, the latter will have no effect without a `block` parent. If it's getting `display:flex` from some other ancestor, again you're not really doing BEM.

Comment: Hmm yeah, that is true. But still, the usage of BEM and SCSS lets me better structure and visualize all my child themes code. But thanks for the input

Comment: If it's helping you structure your code, that's great. If you can get the layout you're looking for without fully using BEM that's fine; go for it. Programming is all about making compromises, but BEM was created by very smart people, and if your site is big enough and your styles complicated enough, it's entirely possible that these shortcuts will catch up with you sooner or later.